# Data not received after receiving it for few minutes using io.netty 4.1.29

Tags: socket.io, netty

I am using io.netty to receive telemetric data from a device which is configured to an ip address and port.
I am receiving data for few minutes and after that it stops receiving messages.
At the time of not receiving data

1. My  jar is running fine with some process id listening to configured port without any error.
2. There is no error as I can see from the program logs in my business logic.

Below is code snippet

```
//StartTCPServer class
private void startServer(int port) {
        try {
            tcpServer = new TCPServer(port);
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);           
            executorService.submit(tcpServer);
}

//TCPServer class
@Override
    public void run() {
        eventLoopGroup = EPOLL ? new EpollEventLoopGroup() : new NioEventLoopGroup();
      
        try {
            new ServerBootstrap()
                    .group(eventLoopGroup)                  
                    .channel(EPOLL ? EpollServerSocketChannel.class : NioServerSocketChannel.class)                    
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE,true)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR,new AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator(1024,16*1024,1024*1024))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(Channel ch) {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                            pipeline.addLast("decoder", new Decoder());
                            pipeline.addLast("handler",new TcpServerHandler());
                            
                        }
                    })                    
                    .bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().syncUninterruptibly();
        }
```

Can I make following changes to solve it.

1. Increase no of threads like :executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
2. Incease number of groups like: eventLoopGroup = EPOLL ? new EpollEventLoopGroup(20) : new NioEventLoopGroup(20);

What can be done to overcome this.

1. Is is because of thread going to sleep mode or deadlock?
2. Memory issue ?
3. Socket memory is not cleared?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanking all in advance.

Comment: At what rate (how rapidly) do the messages arrive for the first few minutes?

Comment: Data is received every 10 seconds. So initially I am seeing rate of sending from device n receiving almost same. At later part I am observing data r received slowly

Comment: Maybe check with a profiler if you block the EventLoop ?